# How to accurately get the objects that the camera is directly pointed to?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera

I'm trying to pick up objects on my game. so the object that the user is directly looking at can be picked up on a button click. I have `LookObject` which is a `gameObejct` that stores the objects that I'm currently looking at. The issue I'm facing here is that the `LookObject` is NOT accurately showing the objects that I'm looking at.

```
 [Header("InteractableInfo")]
public float sphereCastRadius = 0.5f;
public int interactableLayerIndex;
private Vector3 raycastPos;
public GameObject lookObject; 
private PhysicsObjects physicsObject;
private Camera mainCamera;
public GameObject winUI;
private InteractiveObjects interactiveObjects;
 void Update()
{
    //Here we check if we're currently looking at an interactable object
    raycastPos = mainCamera.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Screen.width / 2, Screen.height / 2, 0));
    RaycastHit hit;


    if (Physics.SphereCast(raycastPos, sphereCastRadius, mainCamera.transform.forward, out hit, maxDistance, 1 << interactableLayerIndex))
    {

        lookObject = hit.collider.transform.gameObject;
       
    }

    //if we press the button of choice
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        //and we're not holding anything
        if (currentlyPickedUpObject == null)
        {
            //and we are looking an interactable object
            if (lookObject != null )
            {
                PickUpObject();            
              
                }
               
            }
        }
        //if we press the pickup button and have something, we drop it
        else
        {
            BreakConnection();
        }
    }



public void BreakConnection()
    {
        pickupRB.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.None;
        currentlyPickedUpObject = null;
        physicsObject.pickedUp = false;
        currentDist = 0;
    }
    public void PickUpObject()

    {
        physicsObject = lookObject.GetComponentInChildren<PhysicsObjects>();
        currentlyPickedUpObject = lookObject;
        pickupRB = currentlyPickedUpObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        pickupRB.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.FreezeRotation;
        physicsObject.playerInteractions = this;
    }
```

[Here is the cube `inspector`][2]

The cube and all other interactable objects have this script:

```
public class PhysicsObjects : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float waitOnPickup = 0.2f;
    public float breakForce = 35f;
    [HideInInspector] public bool pickedUp = false;
    [HideInInspector] public PlayerInteractions playerInteractions;


    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if (pickedUp)
        {
            if (collision.relativeVelocity.magnitude > breakForce)
            {
                playerInteractions.BreakConnection();
            }

    }

    //this is used to prevent the connection from breaking when you just picked up the object as it sometimes fires a collision with the ground or whatever it is touching
    public IEnumerator PickUp()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(waitOnPickup);
        pickedUp = true;

    }
}
```

Comment: Could we have more info on how the cube is setup? Components, scripts and whatnot.

Comment: I edited my question, please re-check

Answer (score 0):

You are doing

```
if (Physics.SphereCast(raycastPos, sphereCastRadius, mainCamera.transform.forward, out hit, maxDistance, 1 << interactableLayerIndex))
{
    lookObject = hit.collider.transform.gameObject; 
}
```

with a radius of `0.5` meters!

Then next you do

```
 Physics.Raycast(mainCamera.transform.position, mainCamera.transform.forward, out hit, maxDistance);
```

without any layer filter so you hit e.g. the floor.

So the check

```
if (hit.transform)
{
    interactiveObjects = hit.transform.GetComponent<InteractiveObjects>();
}
else
{
    lookObject = null;
    interactiveObjects = null;
}
```

enters the `if` case, even then when the `hit.transform` of the second cast is not he same as the first one.

---

I don't really understand why you do two casts in the first place. You probably rather want to simply stick with

```
if (Physics.SphereCast(mainCamera.ViewportPointToRay(Vector2.one * 0.5f), sphereCastRadius, out var hit, maxDistance, 1 << interactableLayerIndex))
// or if you don't want to use a sphere cast anyway
//if(Physics.Raycast(mainCamera.ViewportPointToRay(Vector2.one * 0.5f), maxDistance, 1 << interactableLayerIndex))
{
    var lookObject = hit.collider.gameObject;
       
    if(lookObject.TryGetComponent<InteractiveObjects>(out var interactiveObject))
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            //and we're not holding anything
            if (!currentlyPickedUpObject)
            {
                // whatever happens in here
                PickUpObject(interactiveObject);     
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and simply use a smaller radius for the sphere cast or as commented use the simple RayCast directly if you don't want to use a radius anyway.

---

in general I would also recommend to rather use a

```
public LayerMask interactableLayers;
```

and then directly use `interactableLayers` instead of `1 << interactableLayerIndex`.

Comment: mainCamera.ViewportPointToRay(Vector2.one * 0.5f) is underlined when I type it in VS. I edited my code above and removed some misleading parts. can you check that please.

Comment: Updated .. I forgot to remove the forward vector .. typing on phone

Comment: I have a question tho, why did you pass a variable in the PickUpObject() ? what is the use of it? Also, would it work if I just replaced the InteractiveObject with PhysicsObjects? because PhysicsObjects  is the script that is attached to the interactable objects on my game.

Comment: Well you where the one who had it called `InteractiveObjects` so yeah you can use whatever type you want there. I didn't have the code of your `PickupObject` but I would prefer to rather pass in parameters instead of storing everything in class fields and polling it from there .. the reason: These references are basically only valid for this one purpose and only temporary so why store them in class fields? I would also instead of all the `GetComponent` calls already have them all referenced on one central too level component on your target objects

Comment: This is less related to your raycast issue but rather a code/component Design question ;)

Comment: I'm really sorry, but what do you think exactly is the reason why lookObject is not showing the object name accurately (as in the cube example shown in the image above)? I just wanna know that I'm not confused.

Comment: Probably because as said in my code I don't update any class field but rather use only local variables that only exist within the method scope or even within the `if` scopes ;)